# How to resize an image on ActionBar for iOS

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have the following code for the ActionBar

```
<ActionBar title="" class="action-bar">
    <NavigationButton
        (tap)="toggleDrawer()"
        class="action-bar-item"
        ios:visibility="collapsed" 
        icon="res://menu">
    </NavigationButton>
    <ActionItem 
        icon="res://menu" 
        android:visibility="collapsed" 
        (tap)="toggleDrawer()" 
        ios.position="left">
    </ActionItem>
    <StackLayout class="action-item" android:horizontalAlignment="center" ios:horizontalAlignment="center">
        <Image src="res://ideas_wt_full" width="60%" height="60%" [visibility]="android ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'"></Image>
        <Image src="res://ideas_wt_full" width="30%" height="30%" stretch="aspectFill" [visibility]="!android ? 'visible' : 'collapsed'"></Image>
    </StackLayout>
    <ActionItem android.systemIcon="ic_menu_search" ios.systemIcon="12" ios.position="right"></ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
```

Everything is fine on Android, but on iOS the image is showing in full resolution so it’s so big for the ActionBar.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue setting fixed values for the width and height. So I created a class for the image and set those properties in css. Additionally, I had to careful with the height on iOS, because due the limitations with the ActionBar styles, it doesn't change the height of the action bar and I needed to set a height of 80px.